# Video View android issue

Tags: android

Does the `VideoView` class provide me with any method I can use to toggle between the timelines of the video that I want to play?
Assume that

- I have a video of length 4 mins.
- There are 4 buttons.
- If I press Button 1 the video should play from 00:50.
- For Button 2 the video should play from 01:50
- So on and so forth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummm, how about the `seekTo(ms)` method? See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#seekTo%28int%29).